# Neo4j: deadlock memory leaking

Tags: java, neo4j, deadlock, out-of-memory

I have a large number of contacts and relationships I'm trying to insert (many millions). To speed this up I figured I would batch them up and then have multiple threads insert them concurrently. This will cause a few deadlocks but since I can retry them I don't have a problem with that.

```
   public void doBatch(final Collection<Object> rows) throws Exception {
    int retryCount = 3;
    while(!(retryCount<3)) {
        Transaction tx = graphdb.beginTx();
        try {
            for (Object row : rows) {
                String[] fields = ((String) row).split(DELIMITER, -1);
                if (fields.length < 4) {
                    log.error("Not enough fields to process row:" + row);
                } else {
                    addLineToGraph(fields[0], fields[1], fields[2], fields[3]);
                }
            }
            tx.success();
            retryCount = 0;
        } catch (DeadlockDetectedException dead) {
            tx.failure();
            retryCount--;
            log.warn("Retry deadlock");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            tx.failure();
            throw e;
        } finally {
            tx.finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately after a few hours of running and having lots of deadlocks I run out of memory (GC overhead limit exceeded) even after trying a 10G heap. After analyzing the stack dump I noticed lots and lots of Locks:

```
One instance of "org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.RWLock" loaded by "sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader @ 0xc0271350" occupies 672.139.928 (84,78%) bytes.
The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Entry[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".
```

I've got the impression this is caused by failed transactions not releasing the locks so I limit my code to a single thread which will make sure no more deadlocks happen. After doing this I get to see the normal sawtooth charts caused by garbage collection and no more out of memory errors.
From what I understand the tx.finish(); should cleanup everything right? Or am I missing something here?

I'm using neo4j 2.0.0-M03 in embedded mode.

Comment: Did you look at [batch insertion](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/batchinsert.html)? To speed this up, it doesn't use transactions.

Comment: My code originally came from an older version of neo4j. Back then it was a problem to do lookups on the property of a node during batch. I can't have duplicate nodes with the same property or the schema becomes useless to me. Since the dataset is pretty large I also don't want to build my own index to map these properties to nodeids. I hope this makes any sense :) I'll read up on batch some more to see if this can be done these days.

Comment: how big is typically one batch?

Comment: I think I have a similar problem: As soon as a couple of deadlocks are detected, the database server freezes after exceeding about 10GB of heap size. BTW: I am using the REST-interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I upgraded to 2.0.0-M05 and now I get different behavior. I'm getting a nullpointer on the PersistenceWindowPool class. At least at the moment this class is not perfectly thread safe. They told me it would be resolved in 2.0 but until this happens I'm using my own synchronized version of this class.

https://github.com/bennies/neo4j/commit/d8a0f4732f347f2038ebace83c14d37d4b1f8691

Thanks for all the idea's for alternative solutions :)

Answer (score 0):

What about using lock whenever you are updating any property of nodes of relationship and then release the lock